# How to exit from drawing view?

Tags: java, android, touch

In my app, I have extended the class to view. After finishing the draw(Handout from touch), if I will perform touch event, It should not be invoke on the extended view class. It will perform touch event function of Main Activity.

Code :

```
public class DrawOnImage extends View {
public static Bitmap DrawBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Path mPath;
private Paint DrawBitmapPaint;
private Paint mPaint;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public DrawOnImage(Context c) {

    super(c);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark));
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);


    mPath = new Path();
    DrawBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    DrawBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(DrawBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(DrawBitmap, 0, 0, DrawBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    canvas.drawRect(mY, 0, mY, 0, DrawBitmapPaint);

}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    mPath.reset();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
    if(DrawBitmap == null) {
      setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    }else {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
//                invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    }
    ParameterGetSet.drawingBitmap = DrawBitmap;
    return true;
}

}
```